# Database.convertLead - FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on <sobject>: Validation Formula "<VR name>" Invalid (null) []

Tags: apex, unit-test, validation-rule, lead-conversion

I am getting this error in test classes only when converting lead :

```
caused by: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Validation error on Lead : Validation Formula "VR01" Invalid (null): []
```

The validation work fine from the user interface for any user.

Even if I initialised my settings correctly in my test class, it is failing. This is caused by the hierarchical custom setting usage. The formula for the VR is as follows :

```
AND(
$User.Bypass_RV__c = false,
$Setup.LeadSetting__c.BypassVr01__c = false,   
ISPICKVAL(Salutation,"")
)
```

The question is why $Setup.LeadSetting__c (a hiearchical custom setting) been null in the formula ? Even if I check for null it fails :

```
AND(
    $User.Bypass_RV__c = false,
    $Setup.LeadSetting__c.BypassVr01__c != null,   
    ISPICKVAL(Salutation,"")
    )
```

Using system.runas with an admin user also fails.

I debug the setting just before the convert , and the setting is not NULL :

```
//check setting before converting
            LeadSetting__c ls1 = LeadSetting__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getUserId());
           
            system.debug('## lead setting before update : ' + ls1.BypassVr01__c);
            result = Database.convertLead(lcItem);
```

I suspect the custom setting not evaluated or reachable in a lead convert somehow. Is there any sort of limitation of using that type of setting in leadconvert ?

I saw a post here with the same problem https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Aa1DIAS but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Custom settings are not setup objects.

You need to insert data for custom settings (both hierarchy and list types) in your test like basically every other piece of data. Otherwise, you'll get  (since something like API version 18 or so) a "blank" instance of your custom setting with checkboxes defaulted to `false` (rather than the default you set for them in the Custom Setting definition itself), and pretty much everything else defaulting to `null`.
...at least when being used in Apex.

This, in part, is covered by [the documentation on Custom Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm). While Bob Buzzard did link to it, links tend to change over time. So the relevant section here is

> While custom settings data is included in sandbox copies, it is treated as data for the purposes of Apex test isolation. Apex tests must use SeeAllData=true to see existing custom settings data in the organization. As a best practice, create the required custom settings data in your test setup.

Side note: DO NOT USE `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` unless you absolutely need to. If you don't know with 100% certainty that you need to use it, then you don't need to (and shouldn't) use it.

Be aware that performing DML on Custom Settings is one of the common things that will make your tests basically impossible to run in parallel (deployments will always run tests serially, but running parallel can be a boon for development).

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to require *hierarchical* Custom Settings, consider whether Custom Metadata Types could do the trick and save everyone the deployment grief.

Comment: @Derek F, I already initialised my custom settings in my test class. Also I don't consider @IsTest(SeeAllData=true) an option as I know I will get unexpected result in production afterward.

Comment: @catalandres I am using hierarchical Custom settings because we need to provide different setting for each profile and users.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same.  It's a Known Issue:

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qPxEGAA0/databaseconvertlead-from-apex-test-fails-with-an-internal-server-error-if-it-refers-to-a-custom-setting-inserted-in-the-same-transaction

The helpful official workaround provided is to not insert the Custom Setting record :-)

"*If you skip to insert custom setting records, the test class failures are avoided.
(This is only to pass the test classes, not essentially a fix.)*"

The Custom Setting was essential for my test so I had to resort to `(SeeAllData=true)` with a comment explaining why that was essential.